# MVC Json Cascade Dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to send and receive back the selected value of the cascading dropdownlist.  The codes below work fine for sending all the info to db, but not so upon reloading the view.  The 1st dropdown is OK, the 2nd not so much--it is not "selecting" the selected value.  I want the view of the 2nd ddl to show the selected value.  Thanks!

```
    $('#CatDDL').on('change', function () {
    var catName = $('#CatDDL :selected').val();  
    $('#SubCatDDL').empty();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Product/GetSubCategory",
        type: 'post',
        data: { id: catName },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (getSubCategories) {
            var selectedvalue = $('#SubCatDDL :selected').text();
            $.each(getSubCategories, function (i, item) {
                if (item.Value == selectedvalue) {
                    $("#SubCatDDL").append('<option value="' + item.Value + '" selected="true"">' + item.Text + '</option>');
                } else {
                    $("#SubCatDDL").append('<option value="' + item.Value + '">' + item.Text + '</option>');
                }
            })
        }
    })
}).change();
```

Controller

```
 public ActionResult GetSubCategory(int id, int? selectedValue)
    {
        EFDbContext dbc = new EFDbContext();

        var getSubCategory = from ...
            select new SelectListItem { Text = SubCatName, Value = SubCatID };
        return Json(new SelectList(getSubCategory, "Value", "Text", selectedValue));
    }
```

View

```
@Html.DropDownList("SubCatID", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text", "Select A SubCategory"), new { @class = "form-control", id = "SubCatDDL", name = "SubCatDDL" })
```

Comment: SubCatDDL is emptied before the AJAX call, how could it possibly have a selected value -- $('#SubCatDDL :selected')?

Comment: @paul.abbott.wa.us SubCatDDL.empty to prevent duplication/addition from category change (1st ddl).  The content is reloaded with the selected category.

Comment: Exactly. $('#SubCatDDL :selected').text() will never, ever return a value because the dropdown is empty, so the condition (item.Value == selectedvalue) will never be hit.

Comment: @paul.abbott.wa.us It does not make any difference-unfortunately. I have been thinking/tweaking the codes with no avail.

Comment: What determines the selected value of SubCatDDL?